# Inserting files/file names for extracting after process in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm building a process where after a match is made with a specific doc through a query in SQL Server, a file needs to be sent to a new file share on a Windows server.

Is there a way to hold file/file names (links?) in a table, and then sending them/using a command to move them from a root that holds all the docs to a specific folder?

From reviewing some earlier posts for MySQL, I understood that it's not recommended to store the actual files in SQL, due to resources usage while pulling them, I'd be happy if you could help me with the way to use such names/links in SQL Server tables for later usage.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft SQL Server has FileTables, which I believe fits for your case.

FileTables stores files inside file system. the files can be both inserted/deleted/updated from file system and/or SQL Server. You can attach SAN/NAS storage on windows and redirect your files there.

It also supports clustering.

Please note that, transactional use case is limited.

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/filetables-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

**Edit**

In order to enable filestreams for existing database

```
ALTER DATABASE database_name  
SET FILESTREAM ( NON_TRANSACTED_ACCESS = FULL, DIRECTORY_NAME = N'directory_name' )
```

Comment: I'm reviewing the link you sent but for SQL 2014 (my version). while preparing the prereqs, I understand that if I'd like to make the current DB FileStream enabled, I need to use the alter databaes instead of the 'create' (it's mentioned there), I'm having some hard time changing it to alter using the proided code example on the page.. any tip for the syntex that needs to be changed? - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/create-a-filestream-enabled-database?view=sql-server-2014 Thank you @Simonare

Comment: you first need to open sql server configuration manager , find your sql server instance and from properties you can enable streams. After that you can follow [this instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/enable-the-prerequisites-for-filetable?view=sql-server-2017). please keep in mind that SO is not for Database Administration. dba.stackexchange.com is. Also, If you believe that this post gave you an insight about what you need to do, please consider to upvote or accept it as answer so that everyone can benefit from it. Regards

Comment: I accepted it as it's the answer :) What I meant is that the link I mentioned uses: "CREATE DATABASE Archive   
ON  
PRIMARY ( NAME = Arch1,  
    FILENAME = 'c:\data\archdat1.mdf'),  ..."    BUT from the last comment on that page, for existing DB (I already have a DB I prepared other tables at )I should use the ALTER DATABASE command, how can I modify their example on the beginning of that page to alter my current DB? when tried I was prompted "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'PRIMARY'.", I tried to place "add" instead of on.. any hint would be appreciated. thanks @Simonare !